# jQuery data(...) not stored in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If `data-x` is in the DOM like this :

```
<div id="blah" data-x="143">Hello</div>
```

and I modify it with

```
$('#blah').data('x', 13687)
```

then it seems that the `data-x` is not modified in the DOM (use browser's Inspect feature on the snippet code below) :

[image]

**Is this the normal behaviour?**

---

**Example:**

```js
console.log($('#blah').data('x'));
$('#blah').data('x', 13687)
console.log($('#blah').data('x'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blah" data-x="143">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not loading `<div id="blah" data-x="143">Hello</div>` using ajax or javascript. Else you can try `$('body').find('#blah').data('x', 13687)`

Comment: Yes, it's not stored in DOM, but rather in intermediate storage object (`$.cache`). Changes to data properties made with `data()` method don't affect attributes.

Comment: you need to use $('#blah').attr('data-x', '16387')

Comment: I write you small function if you whant to use .data()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery's `data()` method **does not** set data attributes, it stores the data in an internal object.
HTML5 data attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object, which means the initial value of the data object reflects whatever is given in the attribute, but changing the value with `data()` **will not** update the attribute, only the internal data object that jQuery uses.

So yes, it's normal that the attribute doesn't change, and it's supposed to be like that.

If for some reason you have to change the actual attribute, you can use `attr()`

```
$('#blah').attr('data-x', 13687)
```

Note that this is generally not needed if you consistently use `data()` in your code, and you're not using other scripts that rely on the data attribute.

You'll find more about how attributes are handled, and how jQuery stores the data, in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thanks! If at the end of a session (with modifications on data-x), we need to **serialize** the DOM (including the values of `data-x`), would you do that :
1) LOOP on each element,  2) Do `$('#blah').attr('data-x',  $('#blah').data('x'))` to save data-x into the DOM,  3) Serialize the DOM ... Would you do that or something else @adeneo ?

Comment: @Basj - I probably wouldn't serialize the DOM at all, I think I've only done that once before in a project, and it's not generally neccessary, instead I'd create custom objects conaining values, element name, id, data etc. and if needed those objects could be converted to JSON etc.

Comment: Ok @adeneo. Let's say we have to export the HTML file (with data-x modified during the browsing) with new values of data-x. Would you do the step 1) 2) 3) described in my last comment, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `$('#blah').attr('data-x', 13687)` not `$('#blah').data('x', 13687)` ,because `data()` is not the method to get the attribute data-x to set you have use `attr()` to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('#blah').attr('data-x'));
$('#blah').attr('data-x', 13687);
console.log($('#blah').attr('data-x'));
```

Use the `attr()` function to handle the attributes and their data.

**UPDATE:**
I write small plugin for you!

```
$.fn.dataRead=function(a,b){
    this.attr("data-"+a,b);
};
```

Now work how you need:
example:

```
console.log($('#blah').dataRead('x'));
    $('#blah').dataRead('x', 13687);
    console.log($('#blah').dataRead('x'));
```

Comment: Replacing the *built-in* `data` function is a *really bad idea*. That will potentially break other plugins that store objects in data

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Not only that, jQuery uses `data` internally for certain built in methods to store arbitrary data, which might break if the method is replaced, so it's a **really** bad idea.

Comment: Ok, I just edit that and change function name. You are right about replacing functions.